# jQuery message box close timeout

Tags: jquery

I'm using a jQuery message box plugin from [jquerymsgbox](http://jquerymsgbox.ibrahimkalyoncu.com/). What I'm trying to do is to display a message box and close it automatically using timeOut = 30sec.

```
$.msgBox({
  title: "Ooops",
  content: "Ohh dear! You broke it!!!",
  type: "error",
  showButtons: false,
  opacity: 0.9,
  timeOut:30000
});
```

The code posted isn't working.
I'm just a beginner and don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing something... add this right above `timeout:30000`

```
autoClose:true
```

So you have:

```
$.msgBox({
title: "Ooops",
content: "Ohh dear! You broke it!!!",
type: "error",
showButtons: false,
opacity: 0.9,
autoClose:true,
timeOut:30000});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.msgBox({
title: "Ooops",
content: "Ohh dear! You broke it!!!",
type: "error",
showButtons: false,
opacity: 0.9,
autoClose:true
});
```

Use `autoClose : true`